# Can I use jwplayer for iPad, hiding the controls bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html5-video

I need to manage a video player with fallback to flash (for support IE 8 ) without the controls bar. The user won't be able to interact with the video but with my custom controls.

The problem is the iPad environment. If I use jwplayer, in iPad it will create a default system video player, with its controls bar.

Is there any method to achieve my goal? Maybe managing the video html tag natively, interacting with some JS / jQuery interface?

I tried also flowplayer at this link:

http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/controls-apple-ipad.html

But trying that on my iPad, the video freezes at first frame (not the best result..).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

http://videojs.com/

It has flash fallback and very good documentation.

It also overrides the iPad's native video viewer.